# Spring Rest Controller Patch implementation

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jackson, patch, spring-restcontroller

I need to implement `PATCH` functionality at my Spring `@RestController`.

I saw a lot of questions and the most common approach is to use a plain Java `Map` to do this. Map that allows `null` helps to solve the issue with null or absent values because it looks like impossible to implement on POJO.

Is there at Spring any out of the box functionality that helps to reflect values from Map to the existing model object or I have to implement it by myself.. for example using Jackson and so on ?

Comment: I've put together a [post](https://cassiomolin.com/using-http-patch-in-spring/) that describes an approach for using `PATCH` in Spring. And a working example is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/cassiomolin/http-patch-spring).

Answer (score 1):

I can share My implementation of PATCH, hope this helps some one in some way. I have a client which has six fields like ( name, type, address fields , ID, Number, postcode), I can edit the client and change anything.

this is also an elaboration on the question with a partial answer ( or a complete one if there is no other way than the two below) Or perhaps PATCH is supposed to be done differently

clientService is just a service which holds the ClientRepository

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PATCH ,produces = {"application/vnd.api+json"} )
    ResponseEntity<Resource<Client>> editClient(@PathVariable("id") Integer id,@RequestBody Client editedClientFromBrowser) {
// the id is the ID of the client that I was editing.. 
 //i can use this to retrieve the one from back end
// editedClientFromBrowser is the changed Client Model Object 
//from the browser The only field changed is the one
//  that was changed in the browser but the rest of 
//the object is the same with the ID as well

        logger.info("Edit Client reached");

     //retreive the same Client from backend and update and save it
    //    Client client = clientService.getClient(id);
    //    if (client == null) {
    //        throw new EntityNotFoundException("Client not found - id: " + id);
    //    }else{
    //      change the field that is different from the 
    //editedClientFromBrowser and then saveAndFlush client
    //}

    //OR saveAndFlush the editedClientFromBrowser itself
    clientService.saveAndFlush(editedClientFromBrowser);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);


    }
```

now another method I read on (http://www.baeldung.com/http-put-patch-difference-spring) and tried:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PATCH ,
   produces = {"application/vnd.api+json"}  )
    ResponseEntity<Resource<Client>> editClient(@PathVariable("id") Integer id, 
     @RequestBody Map<String, Object> updates)
```

this one does give me a hashMap. but it gives me each and every field. even the ones I did not change. So, is that really beneficial? No idea seriously, may be it is lighter than getting the whole client object back.

I would have liked if I get only the hashmap of one or two fields which I did change. that would have been more in line with PATCH i think. Can I improve my two implementations in some way?

Comment: What do u mean with it gives u the all fields? That depends on the client, he must create a json (aka the hashmap) ignoring the fields that have not been set, so u will get only the fields to be changed.